# How to add "On behalf of" in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

I have always previously use this, but for some reason now in Google I can't add a custom email address and send the emails via Google's servers.

[image: screenshot1]

**This is bad**

[image: screenshot2]

**The old screen looked like this: this screen used to show this:**

[image: screenshot3]

Have Google removed this fantastic feature?

How can I enable this feature again?

Comment: What happens if you enter your gmail SMTP server settings there?

Comment: I'll give that a bash!

Comment: Ye, google doesn't like it. Sadly :(

Comment: Question about a web-service offered by Google is not on topic here at Superuser.  Of course the alias option is exactly what you want.

Comment: Turns out google have removed this option now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just set this up a few minutes ago to send mail from my primary (personal) Gmail account as my secondary email address (an academic email) that uses Google Apps (e.g. youremail@googleappsdomain.com)

Just make sure you enter the following information during setup:

```
SMTP server : smtp.gmail.com
Username    : youremail@googleappsdomain.com
Port        : 587 (enable TLS)
Password    : enter your Google Apps email password
```

If you get an error message that looks like this:

```
Authentication failed. Please check your username/password.
[Server response: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 p10sm4562279obk.2 - gsmtp code(535) ]
```

That probably means that you have [2-Step Verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/) enabled. If so, make an [app password](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) and use that auto generated password instead of your Google Apps email password.